# how to obtain objects in objects (with all the key names) in SQL?

Tags: sql, node.js, arrays, json, postgresql

my database contains two tables named category and sport:

```
category
-----------------------------------
id        |   title    | ...
1         |   summer
2         |   autumn
3         |   spring
4         |   winter

sport
--------------------------------------------------------------
id        |   title       | description | category_id  | ...
1         |   ski         | ...         |   4
2         |   surf        | ...         |   1
3         |   snorkeling  | ...         |   1
4         |   running     | ...         |   3
5         |   hiking      | ...         |   2
...
```

my question is how to obtain with one request in Sql (postgresql) this result :

```
{
        category: [
                {
                        c.id: 1,
                        c.title: summer,
                        sport: [
                                {
                                        s.id: 2,
                                        s.title: surf,
                                },
                                {
                                        s.id: 3,
                                        s.title: snorkeling,
                                },
                        ],     
                },
                {
                        c.id: 2,
                        c.title: autumn,
                        sport: [
                                {
                                        s.id: 5,
                                        s.title: hiking
                                }
                        ],
                },
                {
                        c.id: 3
                        c.title: spring,
                        sport: [
                                {
                                        s.id: 4,
                                        s.title: running,
                                }
                        ],
                },
                {
                        ...
                }               
        ]
}
```

I've tried with ARRAY_AGG but it removes the key_names and i need it to call the values with in my API.

Comment: Do you actually need JSON or do you want a normal resultset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine `jsonb_agg()`, to_jsonb()`and`jsonb_build_object()`

```
select to_jsonb(c)||jsonb_build_object('sport', jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s) - 'category_id'))
from category c
  join sport s on s.category_id = c.id
group by c.id;
```

The above assumes that `category.id` is defined as the primary key.

It returns one row per category.

If you really want one gigantic array of all rows, you need to aggregate in two steps:

```
select jsonb_build_object('category', jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(c)||sport))
from category c
   join (
    select category_id, jsonb_build_object('sport', jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s) - 'category_id')) as sport
    from sport s
    group by s.category_id
  ) s on s.category_id = c.id
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ef40690219be75c80ee535a6aa1f9d0e)

Comment: the second solution is perfect ! thanks a lot !